# How to stack error bars in a stacked bar plot using geom_errorbar?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to stack the error bars in a stacked histogram using geom_errorbar / ggplot.

In my ggplot statement, I have tried to used both `position="stack"` and `position="identity"`. None of them worked.

Here is my ggplot statement:

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x=factor(year), y=proportion, fill=response)) +
        facet_grid(. ~ sex) +
        theme(legend.position="none")
        geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ci_l, ymax=ci_u),
                      width=.2,                    # Width of the error bars
                      position="identity") +
```

Here is the result I'm getting, and you may notice that the error bars on the right hand-side do not follow the bar values.

[image]

Here is the Data Frame I've used in this example:

```
DF <- data.frame(sex=c("men","women","men","women","men","women"),
                  proportion=c(0.33,0.32,0.24,0.29,0.12,0.16),
                  ci_l=c(0.325,0.322,0.230,0.284,0.114,0.155),
                  ci_u=c(0.339,0.316,0.252,0.311,0.130,0.176),
                  year=c(2008,2008,2013,2013,2013,2013),
                  response=c("Yes","Yes","Yes, entire the journey","Yes, entire the journey","Yes, part of the journey","Yes, part of the journey")
                  )
```

Comment: Your identity and stack labels are swapped. The one on the left is what you get with with `position='stack'`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Matthew Plourde. I'm still hoping for a solution, though.  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is happening here is that `ggplot` is not stacking the error bars (they would have to be summed) so you will have to do that by hand ([and it seems that Hadley thinks that this is not a good idea and wil not add this functionality](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1079)).

So doing by hand:

```
DF$ci_l[DF$response == "Yes, part of the journey"] <- with(DF,ci_l[response == "Yes, part of the journey"] +
         ci_l[response == "Yes, entire the journey"])

DF$ci_u[DF$response == "Yes, part of the journey"] <- with(DF,ci_u[response == "Yes, part of the journey"] +
                                                             ci_u[response == "Yes, entire the journey"])
```

Now:

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x=factor(year), y=proportion)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ sex) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(fill=response)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= ci_l, 
                    ymax= ci_u),
                width=.2,                    # Width of the error bars
                position="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: This should be native, it's hard to do by hand for complex things

Comment: I'm not quite sure this code is correct (any more): it does not reproduce your plot.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `geom_errorbar` is just making nice error bars with the y values that you give it; it doesn't know anything about the `geom_bar` layer which has a vertical offset for some of the data.  So you need to adjust for the fact that for one of your responses, the values plotted have a positive vertical offset determined by the value for another response.  For the example provided, this can be accomplished by:

```
DF$vadj <- c(rep(0,2), rep(c(0,1,0), each=2) * DF$proportion)[1:6]

ggplot(DF, aes(x=factor(year), y=proportion, fill=response)) +
    facet_grid(. ~ sex) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
    geom_errorbar( aes(ymin=ci_l+vadj, ymax=ci_u+vadj), width=.2)
```

The technique for adjustment here is admittedly not especially elegant, and if you need to generalize, be aware that it is very much dependent on the particular structure of the dataframe (i.e. it would have to be changed if the rows were ordered differently).  But it should get your error bars where you want them.