# Find mean and sd in Iris data set and draw graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, standard-deviation

I need to find for every numeric variable in Iris data set mean and standard deviation by Species and draw that in ggplot2 graph with geom_col and geom_errorbar.

This is what I got so far

```
library(tidyverse)
data(Iris)
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise_if(is.numeric, list(mean = mean, sd = sd)) -> IrisData
```

I tried to create a graph but I don't know how to use the geom_errorbar

```
IrisData %>%
  select(Species, ends_with("mean")) %>%
  gather(key, val, 2:5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(key, val, fill = Species)) +
  geom_col()
```

I found that it should look something like this

```
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width=0.2)
```

But I'm not sure how to use it, I added this to the end of code and I get some graph but I'm sure it's not right

```
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = val - sd(val), ymax = val + sd(val)), width=0.2, size = 1.2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot` does not allow stacking of error bars by default. So, you will have to do that by hand [error bar with stacked barplot](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1079) which is not that good. If you want to implement it you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872977/how-to-stack-error-bars-in-a-stacked-bar-plot-using-geom-errorbar), else you can use something like

```
library(tidyverse)
data(iris)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, list(mean = mean, sd = sd)) -> IrisData

iris %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Species) %>% 
  group_by(Species, name) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(value),  
            SD = sd(value)) -> IrisData

IrisData %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, Mean, fill = Species)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean - SD, ymax = Mean + SD), width=0.2, position = position_dodge(.9))
```

[image]

or

```
library(ggpubr)
iris %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Species) %>% 
  ggbarplot(x = "name", y = "value", add = "mean_sd",
  color = "Species")
```

[image]